# When to Use Hadamard Product?

Tags: vectors, hadamard-product

Recently I've heard about Hadamard product which do component-wise multiplication. My question is **when to use this technique?**

If I have 1x3 Matrix A and 1x3 Matrix B, can I assume that I can multiply them using Hadamard product?

Comment: I heard that this kind of product is used in Economics

Comment: The answer to your question is : yes. Hadamard product is sometimes also used in Signal and Image processing.

Comment: "when to use this technique" - if the math calls for it. Recall that the Hadamard product of a matrix and vector is equivalent to multiplying the matrix with an appropriate diagonal matrix.

Comment: On the other hand you can always multiply $B^T A$ or $A^TB$. Or $BA^T$ or $AB^T$.

Comment: @snulty $B^T A$ or $A^TB$ is not Hadamard product of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I understand that :) I was just pointing out the dimensions match up.

Comment: @JeanMarie what about cross product? Both of it will produce different vectors, which one to choose?

Comment: @snulty OK I understand now.

Comment: @Eldeanor Cross product is another way to "multiply" (with quotes) two vectors (but reserved to length 3 ones). The difference with Hadamard product is that the latter is commutative whereas cross product is not commutative, thus the order matters, yes...

Comment: @JeanMarie Ok, thank you for your explanation